# Three nearby numbers in three arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Given three sorted floating-point arrays `a[]`, `b[]`, and `c[]`, design a linearithmic algorithm to find three integers `i`, `j`, and `k` such that `|a[i] - b[j]| + |b[j] - c[k]| + |c[k] - a[i]|` is minimum.

I do have a solution in mind but I don't think that is linearithmic. This is what I have right now:

```
 assume minDiff = // some huge value

 for each entry in 'a'
   find an entry closest to it in 'b' and call it 'closestToA'
   find an entry closest to 'closestToA' in 'c' and call it 'closestToB'
   compute the diff: 
         int currDiff = Math.abs(a[i] - closestToA) + Math.abs(closestToA - closestToB) + Math.abs(closestToB - a[i]);
   Replace minDiff with currDiff, if currDiff < minDiff
```

First of all, I'd like to know if there is any better solution? If not, then am I right in thinking that this solution doesn't have linearithmic complexity? The closest number can be found using binary search.

The question is from "Algorithms - 4th Ed." by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne and I'm preparing for an upcoming interview.

Somewhat Similar question: [Match Three or More Nearest Numbers from arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005929/match-three-or-more-nearest-numbers-from-arrays)

Comment: I haven't read the whole thing through yet but finding the closest element in a sorted array should be done in `logn` time by binary search.

Comment: @biziclop yes, you're right so that fixes one part of the approach. But I still don't know if the approach is correct in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us look at some potential ordering of the elements:

```
a[i] < b[j] < c[k]
```

Then we can see the following claim holds:

```
Target = |a[i] - b[j]| + |b[j] - c[k]| + |c[k] - a[i]|
       = b[j] - a[i] + c[k] - b[j] + c[k] - a[i]
       = 2 * (c[k] - a[i])
```

So, for any possible ordering, this is the minimization of the difference between two elements in two different arrays. So, simply minimize for every possible combination (`a` and `b`, `b` and `c`, `c` and `a`) as shown in the question you gave a reference to (can be done in linearithmic time for each pair).

Once you found the minimization for a pair, finding the matching element from the third array should be quite easy - simply go over that array and check each element.

Comment: linearithmic time for each pair is not linearitmic

Comment: @Silnik: You can find the pair that minimizes between `a` and `b` in linearithmic time. Do the same for `b` and `c`, and also for `c` and `a`

Comment: What if such an element (b [j]) does not exist in the third array?

Comment: @LightningIsMyName: How will your algorithm work for arrays:
1 4  , 
2 5  , 
1 3 6
?

Comment: @LightningIsMyName I think you are right because there is a similar hint in the book but for a diff question. I've not read your solution because I've to ask a silly question first. How did you remove the modulus sign before arriving at 2 * (c[k] - a[i])?

Comment: @user1071840: thanks to this "a[i] < b[j] < c[k]", since than c[k] - b[j] > 0 => c[k] - b[j] = |c[k] - b[j]| etc. The easiest way to notice this rather then calculus is to notice that expression |x - y| can be interpreted as the distance between x and y on the number line.

Comment: @LightningIsMyName Did you go through my solution? I think I'm doing the same, I couldn't write the proof of concept but I worked with a similar theory than the required diff can be minimum only when a[i] <= b[j] <= c[k] is minimized

Comment: @user1990169: I couldn't understand your question - what is there that won't exist?
I'm saying that given any 3 elements, you can create some ordering on them (the ordering may not be unique if some of them are equal) but then it implies that the target is twice the difference between the minimal and maximal elements. And this should not be problematic to minimize

Comment: @user1071840: I'm afraid your solution is not exactly correct. For example, imagine having `a = {1, 2}, b = {-2, 5}, c = {9}`. For `a[0]`, you would choose `b[0]` which is not optimal - even though it's nearest to `a[0]`

Comment: @Silnik: although to tell the truth I'm not sure how my solution would decide among multiple options (you got me there, haven't thought about this), specifically for your proposed arrays - the pair which minimizes the difference among all the arrays is `a[0]=1` and `c[0]=1` - so the solution would pick it, and then test each possible `b[j]` to find which one minimizes the target function (which in our case is `b[0] = 2`

Comment: @user1990169: ok, got it - what if there doesn't exist b[j] between a[i] and c[k]. Interesting, I'll think about it

Answer (score 2):

The following algorithm is almost like merging three sorted arrays into one sorted one.

Keep one pointer for each array (i,j,k for A, B and C respectively). Initialize them to 0.

Then compute the difference between A[i], B[j], C[k] and update the lowest value achieved till now if necessary.

Increment the index in the array for which

```
array[index] =  min(A[i], B[j] and C[k])
```

if it has not reached the end.

That is:

```
If ( A[i] is the least ), then increment i.
else If ( B[j] is the least ), then increment j.
else increment k.
```

Keep doing the above till **any one index** runs past the end or you find a situation where all three A[i], B[j] and C[k] are equal.

**EDIT:**
If there are two duplicate candidates (say A[i] == B[j]), then increment both i and j. See for yourself why.

Also, if A[i+1] == A[i], then simply increment i again.
**End Edit:**

The above algorithm has O(N) time complexity.

**Proof of correctness:**
As shown by other answer, the difference depends only on two extremes of A[i], B[j], C[k].

**So if A[i] < B[j] < C[k], then difference = 2*(C[k] - A[i]). Hence if we increment either j or k, then the difference can only increase. Hence we increment i.**

Comment: Can you add a sample run-though of this algorithm?

Comment: @user1071840 Sorry I can't. If there is an error, or if there is anything you don't understand, please point it out.

Comment: @Downvoter, please tell me where I am wrong so that I can correct my error or delete this answer.

Comment: What happens in case of duplicates?

Comment: It won't work if you do it till 'any one index'. I think you have to do it till all the indices reach their end. Since you can't add a run-through, let me add one. Consider the case {7, 8, 9}, {1, 2, 9} and {4, 4, 9}. If you stop when 'either of the indices' go to the end, you'll miss the actual ans i.e {9, 9, 9}

Comment: @user1071840 First see my edited edit. You have to increment both i & j if A[i] == B[j] and both are less than C[k].

Comment: @user1071840 I meant when any of the index runs past the end. I will edit to make it clear.

Comment: I understood your point, try to run your algorithm against my input. You'll see for yourself. In my input A[i] != B[j]. All I'm saying is that your logic is correct but you'll have to keep going until all indices run past the end.

Comment: @user1071840 When i, j and k are 1 each, Then we increment j to 2, then k to 2 and then i to 2.

Comment: @user1071840 No, if the lowest valued index runs past the end, or if you reach the instance where all three values A[i] = B[j] = C[k], then there is no way you can decrease the difference further. Also, sorry I have to leave now.